# Hide radio button and change box outline color once selected in ninja forms

Tags: css, radio-button, ninja-forms

I am trying to:

- Hide the radio button in Ninja Forms
- Make the box around the answer change colors once clicked on

Does anyone know:

- Which CSS box on Ninja forms I should be inputting the code?
- What is wrong with the code that I tried?

  I tried:
- Inputting code into Advanced CSS associated with List Item Element Styles
- This code:

```js
     $(document).ready(function() {
            $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
                $this = $(this);
                $label = $this.parent();
                $label.parent().parent().find('label').css('background', '#f2f2f2');
                $label.css('background', '#000000');
            });
        });
```

```css
 input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio] {
      visibility: hidden;
      margin: 0;
      width: 0!important;
    }
    input[type=checkbox] + label, input[type=radio] + label { 
      font-size: 16px; 
    }
    input[type=checkbox] + label:hover, input[type=radio] + label:hover { cursor: pointer; }
    input[type=checkbox] + label:before, input[type=radio] + label:before {
      font-family: "ETmodules";
      font-size: 36px;
      position: relative;
      top: 0.3em;
      margin-right: 0.2em;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it is not too late, but the idea to change the Stylized Radio Input is to change the attribute of the tag `label`.

```
label {
  &::before {
    // your code here
  }

  &::after {
    // your code here
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.